# Why Use java.io.Console?

Tags: java, input, console

Just a quick one here.

What are the benefits of using `java.io.Console` as opposed to using a `BufferedReader` wrapping an `InputStreamReader` for `System.in`?

Why would I use it?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `java.io.Console` to present an interactive command-line to the user. You could do all that with `System.in` yourself, but you would have to implement things like noticing when the input was done, or `readPassword`, etc.

Comment: erasing characters? Isn't that performed by the system console it self?

Comment: If you use a BufferedReader around System.in then you don't need to "notice" the erasing of characters or any of that stuff. <code>readPassword</code> is a good reason to use Console, though.

Comment: Thanks guys, you're right. I removed the part about erasing characters.

Answer (score 10):

Because it's code that is already written for you...no need to re-invent the wheel. Chances are, you're not going to get it any better than it already is.

Comment: that's true! so are you saying i shouldn't develop my own linked list generic types as well for each project?! :P

Answer (score 6):

See [java.io.Console is finally here!](http://blogs.oracle.com/alanb/entry/java_io_console_is_finally)

> One of the most popular feature
>   requests for J2SE in recent times has
>   been the request to improve console
>   support and provide a way to enter
>   passwords with echo disabled.
>   Developers know this feature 4050435
>   as it has been skulking in the Top 25
>   RFEs list for some time.

Comment: Archive link: https://web.archive.org/web/20111005173512/https://blogs.oracle.com/alanb/entry/java_io_console_is_finally

Answer (score 3):

java.io.Console only works when you start a Java program from a command line without redirecting STDIN/STDOUT.

The main advantage I see with Console over System.in is that you have the readPassword() method, which won't echo the characters typed by the user (I couldn't find a way to do this with System.in).

You also have readLine() which will present a prompt and read a single line. You don't have to create your own LineNumberReader.

But, if you want your Java program to be able to read from STDIN when it's redirected from a file or pipe, you still have to use System.in.

Answer (score 2):

Another trick I'm pretty sure you won't get with Console--I created my own input and output streams and replaced System.in/out with them.  My implementation of the stream appended to a log file as well as echoing to the screen.

When I turned on my poor-man's "Debug Info", I could even have it tell me what program/line the sysout came from (It was slow though.  It created an exception and examined the appropriate stack entry so it was off by default)

Answer (score -2):

`java.io.Console` is used to take and read input from the user at runtime and output are displayed after processing the input from user.

For more and detailed information visit https://www.examsmyantra.com/article/58/java/java-io---console-input-and-output