# java.io.Console - like utility that's compatible with stdin redirection?

Tags: java

Is there a utility class in some Java library offering amenities like those of [java.io.Console](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) but compatible with Bash pipe redirection of input?

The following code:

```
import java.io.Console;
public class Foo {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Console cons = System.console();
    String foo = cons.readLine(); // line-5
  }
}
```

will throw a NPE on line-5 when doing a:

```
echo "test" | java Foo
```

This is also mentioned [in this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972813/why-use-java-io-console) without offering any alternatives save the use of **System.in**.

Comment: What's wrong with using `System.in` here? After all that's exactl what you're after: the system input stream (also known as `stdin`).

Comment: Nothing's wrong with System.in I was just wondering whether I could have my cake and eat it too..

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String foo = in.readLine(); // line-5
        System.out.println(foo);
    }
}
```

The password related features should be done manually.